# Are there performance benefits from separating data calculations from data formatting in Kotlin app?

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, readability

I have a codebase where all my data calculations and data formatting occur within a single function. Are there any performance benefits to separating these out into separate functions or does separating them only improve readability?

I know that I should separate them but I don't really know all the reasons why.

Here is the function I am referring to:

```
private fun processData(data: ByteArray) {
        progressBar.visibility = GONE
        Log.d(TAG, "displayDiagnosticData: ")

        val bmsVersionView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview_bms_version)
        val boardVersionView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview_board_version)
        val cellOneView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview_cell_1)
        val cellTwoView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview_cell_2)
        val cellThreeView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview_cell_3)
        val cellFourView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview_cell_4)
        val cellFiveView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview_cell_5)
        val cellSixView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview_cell_6)
        val cellSevenView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview_cell_7)
        val cellEightView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview_cell_8)
        val cellNineView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview_cell_9)
        val cellTenView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview_cell_10)
        val cellElevenView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview_cell_11)
        val cellTwelveView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview_cell_12)
        val cellThirteenView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview_cell_13)
        val cellFourteenView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview_cell_14)
        val packTotalView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview_diagnostic_voltage)
        val packSocView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview_diagnostic_soc)
        val chargeTempView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview_charge_temp)
        val dischargeTempView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview_discharge_temp)
        val chargeCurrentView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview_diagnostic_charge_current)
//        val dischargeCurrentView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview_diagnostic_discharge_current)
        val dischargeCircuitStateView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview_discharge_circuit)
        val chargeCircuitStateView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview_charge_circuit)
        val balanceCircuitStateView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview_balance_circuit)
        val emptyCircuitStateView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview_empty_circuit)

        val bmsVersion = data[0] + (data[1] * 256)
        val cellOne = data[2].toDouble() / 100 + 3.52
        val cellTwo = data[3].toDouble() / 100 + 3.52
        val cellThree = data[4].toDouble() / 100 + 3.52
        val cellFour = data[5].toDouble() / 100 + 3.52
        val cellFive = data[6].toDouble() / 100 + 3.52
        val cellSix = data[7].toDouble() / 100 + 3.52
        val cellSeven = data[8].toDouble() / 100 + 3.52
        val cellEight = data[9].toDouble() / 100 + 3.52
        val cellNine = data[10].toDouble() / 100 + 3.52
        val cellTen = data[11].toDouble() / 100 + 3.52
        val cellEleven = data[12].toDouble() / 100 + 3.52
        val cellTwelve = data[13].toDouble() / 100 + 3.52
        val cellThirteen = data[14].toDouble() / 100 + 3.52
        val cellFourteen = data[15].toDouble() / 100 + 3.52
        val totalVoltage = 47.8 + (data[16].toDouble() / 10)
        val chargeTempCelsius = data[19]
        val dischargeTempCelsius = data[20]
        val chargeTempFahr = (chargeTempCelsius * 9.0 / 5.0) + 32.0
        val dischargeTempFahr = (dischargeTempCelsius * 9.0 / 5.0) + 32.0
        val chargeCurrent = data[21]
//        val dischargeCurrent = (data[23].toDouble() * 100 + data[22]).toInt()
        val chargeCircuitState = data[25].toInt()
        val dischargeCircuitState = data[26].toInt()
        val balanceCircuitState = data[27].toInt()
        val emptyCircuitState = data[28].toInt()

        val chargeCircuit: String = if (chargeCircuitState == 1) {
            "On"
        }else {
            "Off"
        }

        val dischargeCircuit: String = if (dischargeCircuitState == 1) {
            "On"
        }else {
            "Off"
        }

        val balanceCircuit: String = if (balanceCircuitState == 1) {
            "On"
        }else {
            "Off"
        }

        val emptyCircuit: String = if (emptyCircuitState == 1) {
            "On"
        }else {
            "Off"
        }

        val bmsVersionString = SpannableString("BMS Version: $bmsVersion")
        bmsVersionString.setSpan(StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, 11, 0)
        val boardVersionString = SpannableString("Board Version: 2.1")
        boardVersionString.setSpan(StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, 13, 0)
        val cellOneString = SpannableString("Cell 1: %.2fV".format(cellOne))
        cellOneString.setSpan(StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, 6, 0)
        val cellTwoString = SpannableString("Cell 2: %.2fV".format(cellTwo))
        cellTwoString.setSpan(StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, 6, 0)
        val cellThreeString = SpannableString("Cell 3: %.2fV".format(cellThree))
        cellThreeString.setSpan(StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, 6, 0)
        val cellFourString = SpannableString("Cell 4: %.2fV".format(cellFour))
        cellFourString.setSpan(StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, 6, 0)
        val cellFiveString = SpannableString("Cell 5: %.2fV".format(cellFive))
        cellFiveString.setSpan(StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, 6, 0)
        val cellSixString = SpannableString("Cell 6: %.2fV".format(cellSix))
        cellSixString.setSpan(StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, 6, 0)
        val cellSevenString = SpannableString("Cell 7: %.2fV".format(cellSeven))
        cellSevenString.setSpan(StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, 6, 0)
        val cellEightString = SpannableString("Cell 8: %.2fV".format(cellEight))
        cellEightString.setSpan(StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, 6, 0)
        val cellNineString = SpannableString("Cell 9: %.2fV".format(cellNine))
        cellNineString.setSpan(StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, 6, 0)
        val cellTenString = SpannableString("Cell 10: %.2fV".format(cellTen))
        cellTenString.setSpan(StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, 7, 0)
        val cellElevenString = SpannableString("Cell 11: %.2fV".format(cellEleven))
        cellElevenString.setSpan(StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, 7, 0)
        val cellTwelveString = SpannableString("Cell 12: %.2fV".format(cellTwelve))
        cellTwelveString.setSpan(StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, 7, 0)
        val cellThirteenString = SpannableString("Cell 13: %.2fV".format(cellThirteen))
        cellThirteenString.setSpan(StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, 7, 0)
        val cellFourteenString = SpannableString("Cell 14: %.2fV".format(cellFourteen))
        cellFourteenString.setSpan(StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, 7, 0)
        val packTotalString = SpannableString("Pack Total: %.1fV".format(totalVoltage))
        packTotalString.setSpan(StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, 10, 0)
        val socString = SpannableString("SOC: ${data[17].toInt()}%")
        socString.setSpan(StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, 3, 0)
        val chargeTempString = SpannableString("Charge Temp: ${chargeTempFahr.toInt()}" + "°F")
        chargeTempString.setSpan(StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, 11, 0)
        val dischargeTempString = SpannableString("Discharge Temp: ${dischargeTempFahr.toInt()}" + "°F")
        dischargeTempString.setSpan(StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, 15, 0)
        val chargeCurrentString = SpannableString("Charge Current: $chargeCurrent" + "A")
        chargeCurrentString.setSpan(StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, 14, 0)
//        val dischargeCurrentString = "Discharge Current: $dischargeCurrent" + "A"
        val chargeCircuitStateString = SpannableString("Charge Circuit: $chargeCircuit")
        chargeCircuitStateString.setSpan(StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, 14, 0)
        val dischargeCircuitStateString = SpannableString("Discharge Circuit: $dischargeCircuit")
        dischargeCircuitStateString.setSpan(StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, 17, 0)
        val balanceCircuitStateString = SpannableString("Balance Circuit: $balanceCircuit")
        balanceCircuitStateString.setSpan(StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, 15, 0)
        val emptyCircuitStateString = SpannableString("Empty Circuit: $emptyCircuit")
        emptyCircuitStateString.setSpan(StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, 13, 0)


        bmsVersionView.text = bmsVersionString
        boardVersionView.text = boardVersionString
        cellOneView.text = cellOneString
        cellTwoView.text = cellTwoString
        cellThreeView.text = cellThreeString
        cellFourView.text = cellFourString
        cellFiveView.text = cellFiveString
        cellSixView.text = cellSixString
        cellSevenView.text = cellSevenString
        cellEightView.text = cellEightString
        cellNineView.text = cellNineString
        cellTenView.text = cellTenString
        cellElevenView.text = cellElevenString
        cellTwelveView.text = cellTwelveString
        cellThirteenView.text = cellThirteenString
        cellFourteenView.text = cellFourteenString
        packTotalView.text = packTotalString
        packSocView.text = socString
        chargeTempView.text = chargeTempString
        dischargeTempView.text = dischargeTempString
        chargeCurrentView.text = chargeCurrentString
//        dischargeCurrentView.text = dischargeCurrentString
        chargeCircuitStateView.text = chargeCircuitStateString
        dischargeCircuitStateView.text = dischargeCircuitStateString
        balanceCircuitStateView.text = balanceCircuitStateString
        emptyCircuitStateView.text = emptyCircuitStateString

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance?  No.  Maintainability?  Yes.  Separation of concerns is one of the core tenets of modern software architecture.  Combining the two things makes a difficult to read, difficult to debug mess.  Separating them allows you to concentrate on one thing at a time, and makes it easier for people maintaining the code (which may even be you 6 months from now when fixing a bug and you've forgotten how it works) to understand the logic and flow of the program.

That function you posted would not be accepted in any professional codebase.  It's too long, it does too many things.  It needs to be broken up.

Answer (score 1):

Your bigger problem there is that you're repeating yourself, a lot. Not only does that make the whole thing longer, and arguably harder to read, it also makes it hard to maintain like Gabe says, and makes it far more likely a bug will sneak in there. Imagine you needed to add another row of cells - there's a lot of boilerplate involved, a lot of repetitive work, and that's where humans tend to mess up

Like as an example of the kind of thing you can do - see how your cell data is basically taken from a range of values in `data`, with the same calculation applied to each? You could do this instead:

```
val cells = (2..15).map { index -> data[index].toDouble() / 100 + 3.52 }
```

or, to keep things more explicit and separate:

```
// Except give this a good name since it's doing something specific
// Because this is some kind of conversion formula, putting it in its own function
// makes it easy to maintain and document, and it's clear exactly what it is
fun getCellValue(dataValue: Int) = dataValue.toDouble() / 100 + 3.52

val cells = (2..15).map { index -> getCellValue(data[index]) }
```

Now you have one or two lines replacing 14 lines of initialisation code. It's also easier to make changes - if the format of `data` changes, you can easily change the range of indices to use, or the formula applied to each value. It's one place, instead of on each line, where you have to update each one and make sure you haven't made a typo or skipped one.

---

And when you have structured data like that, it can make your other code easier to work with too - because instead of needing to work with separate variables, you can work with indices and loop over things instead of writing each step out:

```
// no need for a separate line for each with hardcoded values if you can work it out
// (Because it's a separate function, you can use it for the other display lines too,
// it's not cell-specific)
fun SpannableString.applyBoldPrefix() = apply {
    val colonIndex = indexOf(':')
    if (colonIndex >= 0) setSpan(StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, colonIndex, 0)
}

// you could also just pass in the index and look up cells[index] here -
// this is a more functional approach, but whatever's good
fun getCellDisplayString(cellIndex: Int, cellData: Double) =
    SpannableString("Cell ${cellIndex + 1}: %.2fV".format(cellData))
        .applyBoldPrefix()

// lots of ways to define/grab a set of views programmatically - putting them all
// in a container you can look up is one way. You can also generate resource identifier
// strings, like "R.id.textview_cell_$i" and look that up
val cellTextViews = findViewById<ViewGroup>(R.id.containerHoldingCells)
    .children.filterIsInstance<TextView>

// now you can just iterate over stuff to complete the repetitive task
cellTextViews.forEachIndexed { i, view ->
    view.text = getCellDisplayString(i, cells[i])
}
```

That's about half your code right there. I wouldn't necessarily structure everything this way (I feel like given you're working with a data format here, a more formal structure definition would be helpful, and you can generalise more too) and it's a bit rough-and-ready, but hopefully it gives you a general sense of how you can cut things down, but also make it easier to maintain them and try out changes

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! I hadn't considered repetition being a bigger problem before, but I will update my code as you recommend.

Comment: @DylonJaynes no worries! Yeah basically, if you end up repeating code, you probably want to extract a function from that so you can write it once and reuse it. If it's only a little repetition it really depends on the situation, but for something like this you can absolutely trim it down into reusable pieces. It really helps a lot!

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I implemented a better (although not perfect I'm sure) solution today and I am already seeing how much nicer it is to have it split into bite sized pieces. I actually posted my code in an answer below. Does that look better or do you think I could break it up even more? Again, thank you for your help!

Comment: @DylonJaynes yeah, that's way better huh! There's obviously more repetitive stuff (like the TextView references) that would be nice to handle as a loop instead of having to write them out, but you do get to a point where it's like, is it better to be explicit and list things? It really depends. Also I went for the low-hanging fruit with that one, the cells were the easiest stuff to handle as a group - there's still a bit you could do with the others, but it's not as obvious. Good call with the on/off stuff! I'd refactor that temperature conversion into a function too (you use it twice)

Comment: I guess I should have said you can get diminishing returns the more you do it - and you have to be careful you don't start combining things that should be handled separately, just because they happen to look similar! But once you have the idea in your head, you can start to spot ways to make things more readable and elegant. It can be pretty satisfying! I feel like you've got a sense of it huh ;)

Comment: Yeah, I would say I've got somewhat of a sense now. Thanks for leading me down that path!

Answer (score 0):

I condensed my code a lot more and created functions to process separate chunks of data. I also was able to get rid of a lot of my repetitious code. For anyone who is interested, here is the updated code:

```
private fun String.withStyling() = SpannableString(this).apply {
        setSpan(StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, indexOfFirst { it == ':' }, 0)
    }

private fun processDiagnosticData(data: ByteArray) {
        binding.progressBarCyclic.visibility = GONE
        Log.d(TAG, "displayDiagnosticData: ")

        processCells(data)

        processTemps(data[19], data[20])

        processCircuits(data)

        processOtherData(data)
    }

    // Process cells 1-14 and display.
    private fun processCells(data: ByteArray) {
        val cellViews = listOf(
            binding.textviewCell1,
            binding.textviewCell2,
            binding.textviewCell3,
            binding.textviewCell4,
            binding.textviewCell5,
            binding.textviewCell6,
            binding.textviewCell7,
            binding.textviewCell8,
            binding.textviewCell9,
            binding.textviewCell10,
            binding.textviewCell11,
            binding.textviewCell12,
            binding.textviewCell13,
            binding.textviewCell14
        )

        for ((i, cellView) in cellViews.withIndex()) {
            val value = data[2 + i].toDouble() / 100 + 3.52
            val cellNumberString = (i + 1).toString()
            val formattedString = "Cell $cellNumberString: %.2fV".format(value).withStyling()
            cellView.text = formattedString
        }
    }

    // Process charge/discharge temps and display.
    private fun processTemps(chargeTempCel: Byte, dischargeTempCel: Byte) {
        val chargeTempFahr = chargeTempCel * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0
        val dischargeTempFahr = dischargeTempCel * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0
        val chargeTempString = "Charge Temp: $chargeTempFahr°F".withStyling()
        val dischargeTempString = "Discharge Temp: $dischargeTempFahr°F".withStyling()
        binding.textviewChargeTemp.text = chargeTempString
        binding.textviewDischargeTemp.text = dischargeTempString
    }

    // Process circuit states and display.
    private fun processCircuits(data: ByteArray) {
        val circuitViews = listOf(
            binding.textviewChargeCircuit,
            binding.textviewDischargeCircuit,
            binding.textviewBalanceCircuit,
            binding.textviewEmptyCircuit
        )

        val circuitNames = listOf(
            "Charge Circuit: ",
            "Discharge Circuit: ",
            "Balance Circuit: ",
            "Empty Circuit: "
        )

        for ((i, circuit) in circuitViews.withIndex()) {
            val value = if (data[25 + i].toInt() == 1) {
                "On"
            } else {
                "Off"
            }
            val formattedString = (circuitNames[i] + value).withStyling()
            circuit.text = formattedString
        }
    }

    // Process the rest of the data and display.
    private fun processOtherData(data: ByteArray) {

        val totalVoltage = 47.8 + (data[16].toDouble() / 10)
        val packSoc = data[17].toInt()
        val chargeCurrent = data[21]
//        val dischargeCurrent = (data[23].toDouble() * 100 + data[22]).toInt()

        val bmsVersionString = "BMS Version: ${data[0] + (data[1] * 256)}".withStyling()
        val boardVersionString = "Board Version: 2.1".withStyling()
        val totalVoltageString = "Pack Total: %.1fV".format(totalVoltage).withStyling()
        val packSocString = "SOC: ${packSoc}%".withStyling()
        val chargeCurrentString = "Charge Current: ${chargeCurrent}A".withStyling()
//        val dischargeCurrent = "Discharge Current: $dischargeCurrentA".withStyling()

        binding.textviewBmsVersion.text = bmsVersionString
        binding.textviewBoardVersion.text = boardVersionString
        binding.textviewDiagnosticVoltage.text = totalVoltageString
        binding.textviewDiagnosticSoc.text = packSocString
        binding.textviewDiagnosticChargeCurrent.text = chargeCurrentString
//        binding.textviewDiagnosticDischargeCurrent.text = dischargeCurrentString
    }
```